# iOS(swift) testing in-app billing

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to test in-app-billing for non-consumable. In my project i have 5 contents to buy and then download.Upon clicking a button the user should buy the content.I followed few tutorials did't get idea.Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with **In App Purchase** (`StoreKit`) you should follow this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) by *Ray Wenderlich*, is up-to-date so you'll be able to do what you want with.

Also, you can use some libs like [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) to save time. It's a great library, easy to use and not restricted.

With those informations it will be easy for you to do the job successfully and quickly.

Have a good day!

Comment: I gone through Ray Wenderlich tutorial here he is using table view for in app purchase buy button. how can i add the tableview action to UIbutton

Comment: Call the `RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product)` method on your `@IBAction` of the UIButton.

Comment: If i call this i am getting error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: May be `product` is nil. Did you get the `SKProduct` from the `products` list ?

Comment: yes i am getting in table view case but here it crashes out upon clicking itself..see this is what i am getting in log Not purchased: com.focus.jaagerman.circulatory fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) am waiting for your reply thank you..!

Comment: This is what i have added for Unbutton action@IBAction func buyy(sender: AnyObject) { RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product!) } help me bro...!

Comment: @IBAction func buyy(sender: AnyObject) {
      
      RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product!)
         
    }

Comment: Please add more by editing your post. This is not enough. When are you initializing `product` ?

Comment: I gone through the tutorial as you sugessted. if i implement RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product) inside UIButton action i am getting error at product (i.e I am not getting Skproduct from products list).i don't know how to get the SKproduct from products list.The Uibutton is inside the MasterviewControllerclass

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductCell
    
    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.product = product
    cell.buyButtonHandler = { product in
      RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
    }
    
    return cell
  }
}